# creating an anti cheat in an online web game

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security

I have a simple website with a little game in it. It has a basic scoreboard using express - every time you die the website send a post request to the server with your score and the server adds it to the leaderboard. My problem is that its very simple for the leaderboard to be exploited.
through devtools people can easily just:

- disable the colliders so they cant die and then turning it back on when they are happy with the score
- straight up just set the score to what ever value they want
- use the console to send a post request of their own with a score of their choice

I thought about creating a server side score counter and collision checker but my game is fast paced so I think this would be problematic, not talking about the computing power that it would put on the server if multiple people play at the same time.

Is this really the only solution or are there simpler solutions I'm not thinking of?

server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');

const { json } = require('express');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static('Build'))

app.get('/leaderBoard', (req,res)=>{
    var rawData = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
    var data = JSON.parse(rawData);
    res.json(data);
})

app.post('/leaderBoard', (req, res)=>{
    var rawData = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
    var leaderBoard = JSON.parse(rawData).leaderBoard;

    for(var i = 0; i < leaderBoard.length; i++){
        if(req.body.score > leaderBoard[i].score){
            for(let i2 = leaderBoard.length -1; i2 > i; i2--)
                leaderBoard[i2] = leaderBoard[i2-1];
            
            leaderBoard[i] = req.body;
            break;
        }
    }

    fs.writeFileSync("./database.json",JSON.stringify({leaderBoard},null,2));
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: You should try to move as much as possible server-side (without making the game unplayable on slightly high ping). It would probably be best to use a non-json database so that it works better with higher player counts.

Comment: Instead of reading your `database.json` file every time someone makes a request, read it when the server starts and store it in a variable. It will take more memory, but it will take less time to return the request. As for the anti cheat, any amount of cheat prevention will deter cheaters, but there will always be the pesky few that go the extra mile to reverse engineer as much as they possibly can and figure out a way to bypass it. To prevent this, it would be best to have as much server side as possible. Keeping these 2 sides in mind, it's good to strike a good balance.

Answer (score 1):

A server side check would be imperative if you want to truly avoid any cheating...
BUT, you could always make it harder to cheat on the client side with simple checks, like defining a maximum score change (for example if someone gains more than 100 points in 1 second, then he's cheating).

Using a minified code can't hurt, and you could also replace your variables name by abstract ones (a, b, c, instead of "score").
For that same reason, a collision check shouldn't just be defined by a true/false flag.